# Lost my conformance to Codable after adding an enum

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a struct that is Codable ( or was )

```
struct Person  { 
    let name: String           //<-- Fine
    let age: Int               //<-- Fine
    let location: String       //<-- Fine

    let character: Character.  //<-- Here comes the error (Type Person does not conform to Decodable)
 
}

enum Character {
    case nice, rude 
}
```

Now I understand the error. Every type except the enum is Codable so I'm good up until that point. Now as a way to solve this.. I was pretty sure this would work ..

```
extension Person { 
  private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case name, age, location } 
 }
```

But even after telling Swift the properties I want to be decoded I still get this error? Puzzled.

Comment: You just need this ```enum Character: String, Codable```

Comment: Consider not calling your enum Character - there is already a type called Character for single letters in Strings. Or you might nest Character inside Person so then you would have Swift.Character and Person.Character

Answer (score 3):

Since you excluded `character` from the keys to decode, you need to give `character` an initial value. After all, *all properties need to be initialised to some value during initialisation*.

The easiest way to do this is to give the initial value of `nil`:

```
let character: Character? = nil
```

Of course, you can also do:

```
let character: Character = .rude
```

Also note that you *can* make the enum `Codable`, simply by giving it a raw value type:

```
enum Character: Int, Codable {
    // now nice will be encoded as 0, and rude will be encoded as 1
    case nice, rude
}
```